Excessive use of Javascript window object
I am working on a javascript SDK which works in browser, here they have used window.someVariableName to store a data. We wanted that variable to be accessible any where in javascript code, but this expose the internal variables to the user, which is not secure.
Is there any standard way to handle this?
I created a singleton class in javascript and added all variables in that class with getters and setters.

Any code running on the frontend will be exposed to the user in some way, if you want to truly prevent the user from having access to a variable you should store it on the server and only allow for requests interacting with the variable and not for direct usage of it on the frontend

As @KrzysztofKrzeszewski says, there's no way to completely hide anything on the front-end. However, polluting the window with your own properties is a really bad thing to be doing. Defining your own class is a far better approach.

@KrzysztofKrzeszewski Accessing variable through requests will be slow and hectic process, if you are frequently modifying those variables.

It might be slow, but it's the only way to truly 'secure' the variable. You could try to use web sockets if you have to modify it constantly

This was very common a few year ago before we used bundlers. You used to import a js file like this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="somelib.js"></script>

The file would then declare some globals. Today, in ES modules, that would be:
import "somelib"

The common patterns is to use an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):
((global: any) => {

   // Everything here is private
   const s = "hello world!";
   const doSomething = () => console.log(s);

   // Expose only what you want to expose
   global.Something = {
      doSomething
   };

})(window);

Then you can access it as follows:
windows.Something.doSomething(); // "hello world!"
windows.s // undefined


Note: Private here doesn't mean secure. If you need something to be secure, you should have a get function that sends a request to the server (secured by auth tokens, API key or some other mechanism).

